# Interested in setting up K8s cluster on EC2 instance with Minikube & domain name

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-ec2, kubernetes-ingress

I have an EC2 instance that I use for personal work & projects with very small amounts of traffic (portfolio, etc).

I thought it'd be really cool (although obviously overkill) to set up a dev cluster running my various projects using Minikube and to connect a domain name to this instance.

### Setup

I have an Ingress controller that points to my service, with an IP address that is different than the host machine. I think it's somehow the IP address of the VM, but only accessible from the host machine.

I'd really like to use Ingress because I have a number of projects running with different domain names in use. Seems like the simple & correct solution based on my limited knowledge.

### Problem

Not knowing much about k8s/networking, I don't know how to get external traffic visiting the elastic IP assigned to my instance to be directed to the Ingress controller

### What I've tried

I was thinking that, since this is really only going to be used for dev purposes, that I could try using `kubect port-forward ...` somehow to point to my Ingress controller. But [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#port-forward) `port-forward` reference from the official website says nothing about Ingress controllers.

### Question

What is the most correct way to get external traffic into my cluster via an Ingress controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is not for real production workload I would suggest below approach

1. Instead of using minikube use [kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/) to install a single node kubernetes cluster on the EC2 instance.
2. Make sure to remove the master node taint so that workload pods can be scheduled on the master node meaning the same EC2 instance will host control plane pods as well as workload pods. Command for that is

   `kubectl taint nodes nodename node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule-`
3. Install nginx ingress controller and use `hostNetwork: true` in the deployment yaml. So nginx will listen to the EC2 instance's network on port `80` and `443`. Here is the doc on [this](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/baremetal/#via-the-host-network).
4. Create ingress resource and you can access any service via EC2 instances public IP address.
5. When you have budget for more EC2 instance you can add those as worker nodes to the cluster using `kubeadm join`.

Note: You can use free `t2.micro` which is tier EC2 instance as worker nodes.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this out after work and give the green checkmark if I'm able to get it working. :)

Comment: does hostNetwork: true mean that I'll be bypassing any virtual network providers such as Calico? Or is this just setting the network to hostNetwork for the ingress controller?

Comment: It's just that ingress controller pod will be running on hosts network namespace